# Changing a column's values into 1 or 0 based on a parameter in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have this dataframe that contains a lot of columns and for an example have a look at this:

```
id   Status   Name   Age   Job
213  Active   John   39    Unavailable
415  Inactive Sara   34    Unavailable
941  Inactive Micky  11    Unavailable
993  Active   Zack   45    Unavailable
```

What I want to do is to use the pandas library to assign a value of 1 to the job column if the status of a person is active and 0 if it is inactive.So the original dataframe becomes like:

```
id   Status   Name   Age   Job
213  Active   John   39    1
415  Inactive Sara   34    0
941  Inactive Micky  11    0
993  Active   Zack   45    1
```

And to change the values of status column to 1 and 0 based if status is active or inactive respectively.

```
id   Status   Name   Age   Job
213    1      John   39    Unavailable
415    0      Sara   34    Unavailable
941    0      Micky  11    Unavailable
993    1      Zack   45    Unavailable
```

I read a lot in their documentation but they haven't really explicitly declared such manipulations. Also I want to have these made separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I like `map`:

```
df['Job'] = df.Status.map({'Active':1, 'Inactive':0})
>>> df
    id    Status   Name  Age  Job
0  213    Active   John   39    1
1  415  Inactive   Sara   34    0
2  941  Inactive  Micky   11    0
3  993    Active   Zack   45    1
```

Since you only have 2 options (`Active` or `Inactive`), you could also use `np.where`:

```
df['Job'] = pd.np.where(df.Status == 'Active', 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `eq`:

```
df.assign(Job=df.Status.eq('Active').astype(int))
```

```
    id    Status   Name  Age  Job
0  213    Active   John   39    1
1  415  Inactive   Sara   34    0
2  941  Inactive  Micky   11    0
3  993    Active   Zack   45    1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `pd.get_dummies` since you are active or inactive. Might be a little faster on larger `DataFrames`.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Job'] = pd.get_dummies(df.Status)['Active']
#    id    Status   Name  Age  Job
#0  213    Active   John   39    1
#1  415  Inactive   Sara   34    0
#2  941  Inactive  Micky   11    0
#3  993    Active   Zack   45    1
```